# Center of mass of a Soda Can

Tags: homework-and-exercises, everyday-life

I have the following problem and can't seem to get my head around it:

> The mass of the beverage in a full soda can is $m$. The empty can's height is $H$ and mass $M$. A small hole will be drilled on top and bottom of a full can (this doesn't affect the mass distribution) and the can is placed on the table so that the soda drains out. The level of the soda's surface $x$ therefore goes from $H$ to $0$.
>
> a) Find the height of the center of mass for soda+can $h(x)$
>
> b) With which value of $x$ does $h(x)$ attain its minumum value?

My problem is with the mass of the soda. I assumed that it would be $m(x/H)$ so that the soda cylinder's mass is equal to $x/H$ times the initial mass. Using this and height $x/2$ for the position vector of the center of mass of the soda, I arrive at a second-order equation for $x$ which has no real roots...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have two masses to be concerned with therefore:

$$Y_{cm} = \frac{\frac{M_{can}H_{can}}{2}+\frac{\rho_{s}D_{soda}D_{soda}}{2}}{M_{can}+\rho_{s}D_{soda}}$$

where $\rho_{s}$ equals the mass per unit height of soda in the can. Now take the derivative of $Y_{cm}$ with respect to $D_{soda}$ and set that equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks for enlarging that HDE! I was actually trying to figure out how to do that. Thanks again.